# Infowindow bug in android browser. Sencha touch

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I'm Using sencha Architect (sencha touch 2) and when creating a simple infowindow in a google map it displays all the google controls (undo arrow, +, -, zoom controls) next to the closing 'x'.

This only bugs in android (4.0.3) browser, in chrome or firefox on my pc works fine.

I uploaded the Sencha Architect project [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1icVXjWL_BUNFdORVN6dnQyc3M/edit?usp=sharing)

Here's the code for creating and displaying the infowindow.

```
var map = this.getGoogleMap().getMap();

var center = map.getCenter();

var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

iw.setContent('<p> Test </p>');
iw.setPosition(center);         
iw.open(map);
```

Any ideas on why is this happening?

EDIT:
Here's how it looks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of the unwanted icons by adding 2 br tags after the content.
Like so: "**iw.setContent('Test [br][br]');**" (The [] must be replaced with a <>)
This bug came with the last google maps update aprox. a month ago.